# Histogram in R from two vectors

Tags: r, histogram

how can I create a histogram in R from known values and counts? Thing is, I need to change manually h\$counts in my data set, so I have no data for that new histogram with changed values in h\$counts. So, I want to create a histogram from h\$breaks and h\$counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
x = rnorm(100,0,1)
h = hist(x)
newCounts = rep(h$mids, times = h$counts) 
hist(newCounts)
```

You have to use `mids` instead of `breaks` :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I wasn't aware that rep function is working with vectors(new to R).